# Is it possible to get the stored data using another App? using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 app that i want to connect, but my only key is the id, so i want to stored in localstorage the id of the user and get the stored localstorage in another app.

in reactjs i stored data in localstorage

App1

```
localStorage.setItem('UsersId', data.UsersId)
```

App2

```
let UsersId= localStorage.getItem("UsersId")
console.log(UsersId)
```

the result is null

Answer (score 1):

LocalStorage is tied to a single origin, you can't get direct access to data that was stored by a different domain. Unless you are using two sub-domains on the same domain.